# Random variables and Linearity

Tags: random-variables, uniform-distribution

I have an equation $Y = 5 + 3\times X$ and I assume that $X$ is a random variable taking values from a uniform distribution. Can I consider that also $Y$ is a random variable which takes values from a uniform distribution also but in different space?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Got something from an answer?

Answer (score 4):

If X is uniform on (0,1) then Y=5+3X is uniform on (5,8). More generally, for every nonzero b, Z=a+bX is uniform on (a,a+b).

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert, but I think $Y$ will be distributed uniformly as well.

#### Right attempt

Thank you for pointing out the error Did!

The uniform (continuous) distribution is determined by its cumulative distrubition function.

$$P(X \leq x) = F_X(x)= \begin{cases} 0  &\text{if } x < a\\
\frac{x-a}{b-a}  &\text{if } x \in [a,b[ \\
1 &\text{if } x \geq b\end{cases}$$

Looking at $F_Y(y)$:

$$F_Y(y) = P(Y\leq y) = P(5+3X \leq y) = P\left(X \leq \frac{y-5}{3}\right)$$

You can find the boundaries where this makes sense using:
$$\frac{y-5}{3} \geq a \qquad \frac{y-5}{3} < b$$

Which concludes towards:
$$P(Y \leq y) = F_Y(y)= \begin{cases} 0  &\text{if } y < 3a+5\\
\frac{\frac{y-5}{3}-a}{b-a}  &\text{if } x \in [3a+5,3b+5[ \\
1 &\text{if } x \geq 3b+5\end{cases}$$

#### Wrong attempt

($X$ will **not** be discrete, the overal idea was fine though)

<del>If $X \stackrel{d}{=} U(a,b)$ then 
$$P(X =x) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{b-a} \quad &\text{ if } x \in [a,b] \\ 0 &\text{ if not}\end{cases}$$</del>

<del>Looking at $P(Y=y)$ which determines the distribution you get:
$$P(Y=y) = P(5+3X = y) = P\left(X = \frac{y-5}{3}\right)$$</del>

<del>Which means $Y$ will also be distributed uniformly.</del>

Comment: Note that P(Y=y)=0 for every y.

Comment: @Did Why is that? (Ah, because of continious variables i guess?)

Comment: Definition, wikipedia, textbooks, anything.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out, I guess the current attempt would make more sense ;)